# Override order_new_guest.html email template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, overrides, email-templates

In my custom module i want to override new order email template which will be sent after customer placed an order, what i've done so far are created the file in

> app/design/namespace/module/Magento_Sales/email/order_new_guest.html

and it's not working at all, and i created the **requirejs-config.js**:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Sales/email/order_new_guest.html':
              'Namespace_Module/email/order_new_guest.html'
        }
  }
};
```

the code above should load **Namespace/Module/view/front/email/order_new_guest.html** but its still not working at all

Comment: `magento\app\design\frontend\Vendor\YourTheme\Magento_Sales\email\order_new_guest.html`

Comment: @AnkitShah what is porto_child?

Comment: Please check edited version ur theme name

Comment: @AnkitShah is there a way not to depend on what theme im currently using? or can i just override the default and set the magento always use the default for this case?

Comment: Yes u need to put in your current theme which ur using

Comment: @IdhamChoudry You are looking to overide email template in theme or custom extension?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya in custom extension

Comment: U want to override in module instead of theme?

Comment: @AnkitShah yes i want to override the order_new_guest.html in Magento_Sales